# python 3.6. Giving syntax error

Tags: python-3.x

[image: invalid syntax]

```
high = 100
low = 0
print('Please think of a number between 0 and 100!')
while True :    
   middle = (high + low) // 2
   print('Is your secret number ' + str(middle) )
   ans = input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to 
         indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed 
         correctly.")
   if ans == 'h' :
     high = ans
     print('Is your secret number' + str(middle) )
   elif ans == 'l' :
     low = ans
     print('Is your secret number' + str(middle )
   elif ans == 'c' :
     break
print('your secret num is' + str(middle))
```

What is wrong in the code ?
The question is
[image: Exercise: guess my number]

Comment: You want people to do your examination test?

Comment: You can post the error message in code format.

Answer (score 0):

```
high = 100
low = 0
print('Please think of a number between 0 and 100!')
while True:
    middle = (high + low) // 2
    print('Is your secret number ' + str(middle))
    ans = input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.")
    print(ans)
    if ans == 'h':
        high = middle
        print('Is your secret number ' + str(middle))
    elif ans == 'l':
        low = middle
        print('Is your secret number ' + str(middle))  # This line lacks of ')' in your code.
    elif ans == 'c':
        break

print('your secret num is ' + str(middle))
```

The `ans` can't be assigned to `high` or `low`. It is `middle` to be assigned to `high` or `low`.